# How to create CSV file in ASCII format in Talend

Tags: ascii

I need to create a file (CSV) by fetching data from DB and need to send this file to another server. Client on other server needed this file in ASCII format.
How to create CSV file in ASCII format??
By default talend support ISO and utf-8 format, how about ASCII??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASCII is the default - [please see this article for more information](https://community.talend.com/t5/Design-and-Development/How-to-convert-csv-file-into-ascii-format/td-p/40506).